# How can I make Bourbon behave nicely for Firefox with regards to box-sizing

Tags: sass, bourbon

In my scss file I have

```
* {
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
}
```

according to the [Bourbon documentation here](http://bourbon.io/docs/#box-sizing)

This produces the desired result in Chrome, but not in firefox. If I apply the box-sizing manually it works as desired.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the Bourbon documentation covers more [details on box-sizing prefix settings](http://bourbon.io/docs/#prefixer-settings)

I had a `$prefix-for-mozilla:   false` hiding somewhere.

Problem solved.

Hope this might help another hapless soul in the future.